# How does the socket works on private chat, all the conversation will happen on the same port?

Tags: node.js, html

For the private chat application, how do we identify the persons port do display the appropriate persons message? 
is there any port limits for users count?

Comment: Each distinct websocket creates a new connection. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket for a brief description on how different connections are correctly maintained: "Unique dedicated sockets are created for each connection.". I also wrote a summary here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596542/how-do-browsers-detect-which-http-response-is-theirs/25596634#25596634, with some links (In summary: 4/5-tuple is distinct for all connections.)

Comment: Anyway, at the node level there is no need to deal with a "port": only existing connections. The connection(s) must establish their own identity such that they can be looked up later - perhaps the a session nonce/ID (that can be used to establish a trust relation that which identifies a user) is transmitted to the server as the first message.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a port as a bus line number. To get to the city center you probably need to get on a specific bus. Then when you're in the city center (aka you're connected) you can do whatever you want.

Each connection is unique and when it comes to private chatting you should probably identify connections somehow and store them in an array, possibly. This way you can send messages only to a specific receiver.

Comment: Is there any limitation of the connection?

Comment: What do you mean? @govindaraj

Comment: Assume that I have an application for with online chat functionality, on the same time around 1000 user connecting.

On this scenario how many port needs to be created also how to handle the performance on this.

Comment: @govindaraj I don't necessarily know how to handle the performance aspect, but I definitely know that one port would be sufficient. You don't have to create different ports. Look at HTTP servers, they operate on port 80 all the time, even when a lot of users are connecting to a website at the same time.

Comment: In server side (php , java) based on session we will be identifying the users, but in socket how do we?